# Helm install Kubernetes Federation v2 error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I tried to use `helm` to install Kubernetes Federation v2, which is instructed by the [official documents](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/federation-v2/tree/master/charts/federation-v2). However, when I input the command

```
$ helm install charts/federation-v2 --name federation-v2 --namespace federation-system
```

I got an error saying that `Error: failed to download "charts/federation-v2" (hint: running`helm repo update`may help)`

Helm version:

```
helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.12.3", GitCommit:"eecf22f77df5f65c823aacd2dbd30ae6c65f186e", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.12.3", GitCommit:"eecf22f77df5f65c823aacd2dbd30ae6c65f186e", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Kubernetes cluster version:

```
gcloud container clusters list
NAME      LOCATION           MASTER_VERSION  MASTER_IP      MACHINE_TYPE   NODE_VERSION  NUM_NODES  STATUS
cluster2  asia-southeast1-a  1.11.6-gke.3    35.247.134.16  n1-standard-1  1.11.6-gke.3  3          RUNNING
```

Does anybody encounter the same problem before? Or can anybody give me some advice about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `Error: failed to download "charts/federation-v2" (hint: runninghelm repo updatemay help)`

Usually I see that message if I run helm from wrong directory, that doesn't have `charts/federation-v2` inside.

This should work:

```
$ helm init .... # add necessary security options* like service account or whatever

$ git clone https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/federation-v2.git
$ cd federation-v2/

# check if everything works in dry-run
$ helm install charts/federation-v2 --name federation-v2 --namespace federation-system --debug --dry-run

# install the chart
$ helm install charts/federation-v2 --name federation-v2 --namespace federation-system
```

- [Helm security options](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/securing_installation.md)

Comment: Thanks! The problem has been solved. And I found that the cluster is defaulted to be set as RBAC, so I need to follow `https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/#use-case-2-enable-helm-in-your-cluster` to fix the tiller problem.